# How should I use the phrasal verb “to d**k around”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, slang, offensive-language, phrasal-verbs

> 1. To waste time
>
>    - Stop dicking me around and get to the point.
>    - Would you please stop dicking around with her?
> 2. To take advantage of
>
>    - You're dicking him around, you know?
>    - Don't dick around with her.

As far as I know, this meaning can be used with this structure *dick someone around* and *dick around with someone*.

My actual question is about the structure. If *dick someone around* and *dick around with someone* could be used with the example meanings. I didn’t type any more meanings because I only know these meanings.

Comment: Are you asking about the grammar (which seems fine) or the meaning (as indicated in the tag).  Can you be a bit clearer about your actual question?

Comment: There's another, more literal, meaning - "to dick around" can mean to have lots of casual sex, and "to dick around with someone" can mean "to have casual sex with someone" usu. implying that the someone in question is being taken advantage of.

Comment: @Charles Bear in mind that *dorking around* is also a possible expansion for **d**k around**. The difference is that is that it is not used transitively.  As soon as you have wildcards, you create ambiguity.

Comment: @tchrist there aren't many words we'd wildcard-out here (dork is not one of those).  Two of those words match **ck and can easily fit into this sentence.  When I saw the title, I read it as the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slang statements are colorful because they use non-standard word meanings but can be understood by the context of the sentence.  So in the case of slang, you cannot say if a meaning is "correct" only if the meaning can be understood.

In this case I would say the meaning is pretty clear, for example you can replace "dick" with just about anything and not lose the meaning of the sentence.  The fact that "dick" is somewhat vulger makes the point stronger but I would say the meaning is still clear with innocuous or made-up words.

> Stop booking me around and get to the point.
>
> Would you please stop flipping around with her?
>
> You're bluzzering him around, you know?
>
> Don't zing around with her.

Comment: +1 for the infinitely replaceable verb. Stop flezzurbelling around!

Comment: See [my comment above](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112074/how-should-i-use-the-phrasal-verb-to-ck-around#comment227682_112074) for cases where the verb is not replaceable.

Comment: @Charles sure but my point is that the context makes the meaning in these cases.  For example if I used "Stop booking me around." In a conversation with a travel agent who consistently sent me on multiple connections, then the "book" would have a much more literal meaning but if I used the same phrase in the context of negotiating the price of an orange at a fruit stand, the stand owner would certainly understand me even though "book" has little to no meaning relevant to buying oranges.